# "failed to retrieve share list from server: invalid argument"

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed fresh copy of ubuntu 18.04. when I use command "smb://192.168.1.190" to access windows sharing it's showing "failed to retrieve share list from server: invalid argument".
I have installed samba,smbclient,gvs package.
But I could not get solution yet.